# Error while running flutter app on iOS "Expected identifier"

Tags: flutter

Im having problemas running my flutter app on iOS and can't manage to find how to fix it, im getting this error on debug

> Failed to build iOS app
> Parse Issue (Xcode): Expected identifier
> /Users/mateusoliveira/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gxfbahqkvmfgonavyldfixxczsxe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/DerivedSources/Runner_vers.c:4:502

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.

Comment: Are you running any native code into flutter?

Comment: @RahulVariya NO